# Why is System.Object not abstract in .NET?

Tags: .net, oop

I know it is commonly used as a lock object, but is that really sufficient reason?
What is the meaning of

```
object o = new object();
```

An non-abstract class is something that represents actual objects. "asdasdf" is a string. What actual instance can there be of "object" class? It doesn't make sense, OOP-wise. My question is if there is some practical reason for its existence (besides being used as a lock object).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes you just need an Object, and nothing else, such as when using a random reference type for things like implementing multithreading locks.  Not making object abstract allows use in those situations. The Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit classes (which is the basis behind the "lock" keyword in C#) can acquire a lock on any given object, regardless of implementation.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to answer that question is to ask another one: is there any reason for the Object class to be abstract? Since there is no reason for it to be abstract, it's not.

Comment: A reason for it to be abstract is that it has no concrete purpose. Things that don't have a concrete purpose should be made abstract to help us as humans better grok APIs.

Comment: That it has a purpose for lock objects is just a bit of a handy convenience... and I guess that's why the designers made object instantiable, even though its got no use by itself.

Comment: If every interface was instantiable with methods doing nothing/benign things, we'd confuse ourselves using them when we shouldn't. That's why they're abstract. I suppose though, they would be useful for fakes in unit tests. It seems to me like object is an exception to this.

Comment: The problem with your argument, Scott, is that interfaces specify a contract, without implementing it; the Object class, on the other hand, not only specifies a contract, but also provides a default implementation.

Comment: Of course, the default implementation for the virtual methods (Equals, GetHashCode and ToString) is trivial and mostly useless. On the other hand, declaring those methods as abstract would've forced all developers to implement them whenever they defined a new class.

Comment: In the end, the decision to make object a concrete class was a pragmatic one. Perhaps I should have said "no compelling reason for it to be abstract" ;)

Comment: I understand Object class provides a default implementation, but that's not a reason for it to be concrete. The Object class could be marked as abstract even though all the methods are implemented.

Comment: However, I do completely agree it was made concrete as a pragmatic decision, and I also agree it should be concrete.

Comment: I suppose in my earlier agrument I used the words interface and abstract a little interchangably (from my C++ background). I should have said 'If every abstract class'

Answer (score 8):

Surely for a class to be abstract means that it has some functionality which requires implementation...

System.Object does everything it needs to thus it is not Abstract.

I think you misunderstand why things are made abstract, it's becuase they contain some useful functionality and don't dictate how you implement some parts of thier functionality.

Essentially they are half made classes, like a model kit, which you get to customise to work the way you want to, but you don't have to roll the whole thing from scratch.

They do not exist to stop you from creating instances of them.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually used quite a bit in System.Windows.Forms where plain old System.Object instances are created to act as keys into per Control instance dictionaries for things like event handlers and property values.  Think of it as a poor man's DependencyProperty but without all the machinery built up around it (and thus no need to define an abstraction like the DependencyProperty class).

The CLR might even have some kind of support for optimizing memory usage of plain old System.Object instances since there are only a couple scenarios where they can be used beneficially.

Answer (score 3):

it shouldn't have a public constructor and, I think, it should be abstract. The object class is the base of all .net objects and have no purpose by itself (ok, locking... but I prefer to have a class Lock : object and the problem is solved).
The excuse "because it doesn't need to be abstract" is poor. We should have reasons to make classes concrete instead of abstract. We don't have any reason to make it concrete, so... it shouldn't, because the main purpose of this class is "to be inherited by all the other classes".

Comment: "We should have reasons to make classes concrete instead of abstract." Why that? Why shouldn't objects simply model domain and responsibilities with one object per responsibility? Nothing needed to be abstract then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is sufficient. Either you allow object to be created or you have to create classes for each structure that's just looking for a static pointer that can be referenced. My guess is that there are other places this is used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let assume that object class is declared as an abstract with some abstract method such as toString,Equals and so on. That means that one has to compulsory override this methods when creating a new class because object class implicitly inherited to any class.

Afterall, it would not make any sense to write forcefully code in all newly class to override basic methods which might not need many times at all.  And if you want to create most methods with non-abstract then what is meaning of creating such classes?

That's why it is concrete class rather than abstract.